# Test Class is not integrating with the other classes (Shape, Square, Rectangle, Circle)

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a program to analyze given shapes and print their color and area. I am writing 5 different classes (Test, Shape, Square, Rectangle, and Circle). I am having trouble getting my desired output. I believe the only class that has an issue is "TestShapes". It does not integrate with the other classes to achieve the right output. I am getting the right area for the program, but the rest is not correlating to what is in the classes.

Below I have provided my code along with my output and desired output.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
package Test;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args){
           
           
                 Shape s1 = new Square("Green", 12);
                 System.out.println(s1);
                 System.out.println("Area is " + s1.area());
             
                 Shape s2 = new Circle("Purple", 3);
                 System.out.println(s2);
                 System.out.println("Area is " + s2.area());
             
                 Shape s3 = new Rectangle("Blue", 5, 9);
                 System.out.println(s2);
                 System.out.println("Area is " + s3.area());    
           
    }
    }

        class Shape {

             String color;
             double area;
        
            public Shape(){ // default constructor
                color = "red";
            }
        
            public Shape(String c){ // constructor
                color =c;
            }
        
            public String getColor(){ //accessor
                return color;
            }
        
            public void setColor(String c){//mutators
                color=c;
            }
            //print method
            public void print()
            {
                System.out.println("Color: "+ getColor());
            }
             public double area(){
                return area;
    }
    }

        class Square extends Shape{ // inherits from the shape class

            double sideLength;
        
            public Square(){//default constructor
                super();
                sideLength = 1;
            }
        
            public Square(String c, double s){ //constructor
                super(c);
                sideLength = s;
            }
        
            public double getSideLength(){//accessor
                return sideLength;
            }
        
            public void setSideLength(double s){//mutator
                sideLength = s;
            }
        
            public double area(){
                return sideLength * sideLength; //calculates the area of the square
            }
        
            public void print()
            {
                super.print();
                System.out.println("Side length: " + getSideLength() + "\nArea: " + area());
    }
    }
        
        class Circle extends Shape{// inherits from the shape class
            
            double radius;
            
            public Circle(){
                super();
                radius = 1;
            }

            public Circle(String color,double radius){
                super(color);
                this.radius = radius;
            }

            public Circle(double r){ //constructor
                super();
                radius = r;
            }
        
            public double getRadius(){//accessor
                return radius;
            }
        
            public void setRadius(double r){//mutator
                radius = r;
            }
        
            public void print()
            { // prints out the information
                super.print();
                System.out.printf("Radius: " + getRadius() + "\nArea:"+ "%.2f\n", + area());
        
            }
            public double area(){
            return 3.14159 * radius * radius; //calculates the area of the circle
            
    }   
    }

        class Rectangle extends Shape{// inherits from the shape class
            double length;
            double width;

        public Rectangle(){//default constructor
            super();
            length = 1;
            width = 1;
        }

        public Rectangle(String c, double l, double w){ //constructor
            super(c);
            length = l;
            width = w;
            }
        
            public double getLength(){//accessor
                return length;
            }
        
            public double getWidth(){//accessor
                return width;
            }
        
            public void setLength(double l){//mutator
                length = l;
            }
            public void setSideLength(double w){//mutator
                width = w;
            }
        
            public double area(){
                return length * width; //calculates the area of the rectangle
            }
        
            public void print()
            { // prints out the information
                super.print();
                System.out.println("Length: " + getLength() + "\nWidth:"+ getWidth() + "\nArea: "+ area());

        }

        }
```

Output:

```
test.Square@6ff3c5b5
Area is 144.0
test.Circle@4b1210ee
Area is 28.274309999999996
test.Circle@4b1210ee
Area is 45.0
```

Desired Output:

```
Shape 1:
Color: Green
Side Length: 12
Area: 144

Shape 2:
Color: Purple
Radius: 3
Area: 28.27

Shape 3:
Color: Blue 
Length: 5
Width: 9
Area: 45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should initialize the objects like the code below and use the print functions inside the classes for example:

`
public static void main(String[] args){

```
    Square s1 = new Square("Green", 12);
    s1.print();

    Shape s2 = new Circle("Purple", 3);
    s2.print();

}`
```

Comment: That worked - thank you. Do you know what I would need to do to get rid of the extra decimal for the output? `Area: 144.0` to `Area: 144`

Comment: There should be more efficient ways but I would suggest changing the fields(radius, area, length) to int and change the return type of methods into an int. Because double values are outputted with a (.0).

Comment: Or you could just cast the method return to (int) to return the int value, not the variable itself.